# Connecting to HSQL via Ruby and shutting server down

Tags: ruby, hsqldb

I'm trying to write a Ruby script to kill a database server on my localhost.

When I run an 'ant hsql' it starts the database (output below) and I have to keep that terminal window open.
    Buildfile: /Users/cparaiso/dev/src/testproject-src/build.xml

```
hsql:

install-parent-pom:
[artifact:install] [INFO] Installing /Users/cparaiso/dev/src/testproject-src/pom.xml to /Users/cparaiso/.m2/repository/org/jasig/portal/uportal-parent/4.0.3/uportal-parent-4.0.3.pom
    [touch] Creating /var/folders/8v/1k2gkj412q1_8084x6lvtbqr0000gn/T/jasig/uportal-parent.pom-110044247-marker
     [echo] Starting HSQL on 8887
     [echo] Using: file:/Users/cparaiso/dev/src/testproject-src/data/uPortal
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Could not load properties from file
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Using cli/default properties only
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Initiating startup sequence...
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Server socket opened successfully in 10 ms.
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:/Users/cparaiso/dev/src/testproject-src/data/uPortal, alias=uportal] opened sucessfully in 377 ms.
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: Startup sequence completed in 388 ms.
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: 2012-03-07 15:32:25.198 HSQLDB server 2.2.8 is online on port 8887
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
     [java] [Server@6f507fb2]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

My question is how can I shutdown the server without using a kill command in Ruby to kill the process?

If I try to kill the process via kill command I get 'BUILD FAILED' and it gets stuck until I Ctrl+C out. This is not what I want. Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you issue an SQL statement in Ruby, but if you connect to the database server and issue the SQL statement `SHUTDOWN`, it will shutdown the server process.